# How to connect to docker via VNC when the docker image is not made by you?

Tags: docker, reverse-engineering, vnc

I'm trying to get started with PANDA RE, a framework developed by MIT Lincoln Lab for Reverse Engineering. Their [website](https://panda-re.mit.edu/) says that beginners should try the tool through docker first. Therefore, I pulled their image and got it to run with the command `docker run -p 5900:5900 --rm pandare/panda panda-system-i386`. The log says `VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5900`.

However, if I use *Remmina* to connect via VNC, it says "VNC server closed connection."

Any tips on fixing this?

If it helps, `docker container ls` prints `0.0.0.0:5900->5900/tcp` for this container

Comment: The issue may be related to `127.0.0.1:5900`, this indicates that the VNC server is listening for only traffic from inside the container. The sever needs to be listening on `0.0.0.0:5900` for your port forwarding to work

Comment: Anyway I can confirm that it's listening on `0.0.0.0:5900`? If it helps, `docker container ls` prints `0.0.0.0:5900->5900/tcp` for this container.

Comment: Nope, that is on your system, not inside the container. I would suggest you use `5901` port from outside `docker run -p 5901:5901 --rm pandare/panda panda-system-i386`, do a exec into the container and install `socat` first and then run `socat tcp-listen:5901,reuseaddr,fork tcp:127.0.0.1:5900`, then try and connect on VNC using `127.0.0.1:5901` and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the `--help` you will get

```
The default display is equivalent to
    "-vnc localhost:0,to=99,id=default"
```

So, in order to get the `panda` to listen to `0.0.0.0` you will need to run it with

```
docker run -p 5900:5900 -ti --rm pandare/panda panda-system-i386 -vnc 0.0.0.0:0,to=99,id=default
```